# Japanese characters: PHP using PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo

I'm dealing with something tricky today... I have a MySQL database with UTF-8 encoding and utf8_general_ci collation. All special characters are inserted correctly but not the japanese ones. Here's the code I use to insert new rows:

```
$dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=000.000.000.000;dbname=db_name", "db_user", "db_pass", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$parameterArray = array();
$parameterArray[":1"] = utf8_encode($message);

$queryResult = $dbConnection->prepare(QUERY_USERS_INSERT_MESSAGE);
$queryResult->execute($parameterArray);
```

Everything goes all right while inserting latin characters, even the special ones like ñ, à, ë,... But when I try to insert japanese characters like たなは MySQL inserts NULL...

Any ideas? I've been googling for hours...

Comment: Using `utf8_encode` on the string is suspicious and should never do anything good on a Japanese string. Also, where does the string come from? What encoding is it in? Maybe see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Yes, I've debugged my code. The string comes from a client-side software and is UTF8 encoded.

Comment: applying `utf8_encode` to a UTF-8 encoded string is a bug.

Comment: So, coming from the client side is the only thing that happens to the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved guys:

@deceze and @Daniel_Vérité got the correct answer.

utf8_encode was the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

The problems solved by adding `utf8_encode` to `$this->conn->exec("set names utf8")`;

**Example:**

```
$this->conn->exec("set names utf8_encode");
```

Thank you.